# Angular Moments Durations - property '_data' does not exist on type 'Duration'

Tags: momentjs

I'm pretty new to Angular. I'm using Moments.js to get the difference between to times. Using duration it returns a object structured like this

```
Duration {_isValid: false, _milliseconds: 0, _days: 0, _months: 0, _data: 
  _data:
    days: 0
    hours: 0
    milliseconds: 0
    minutes: 0
    months: 0
    seconds: 0
    years: 0
 __proto__: Object
```

I'm trying to access the hours value and doing it by

```
const time = time._data.hours
```

It is giving me an error that _data does not exists on type Duration, however the value is showing.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You dont want to use the _data object. You want to call into the function and get the value in hours...

`moment.duration(2, 'hours');`

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Also momentJS is NOT affiliated with Angular.

Thanks!